# As3 - LocalConnection between SWF and AIR desktop app

Tags: actionscript-3, air, localconnection

I need to send a text from an embedded SWF (Web browser) to an AIR based desktop app. 
I did everything like explained in the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/de_DE/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html) but I can't establish a connection.

Does anybody see what I did wrong or can point me to a working example?

From the SWF:

```
function startConnection(e:Event=null):void
{
var localConnection:LocalConnection 
localConnection = new LocalConnection(); 

localConnection.client = this; 
localConnection.allowDomain("app#com.example.desktop"); 

var textToSend = "Hello world! Source: http://www.foobar.com";
localConnection.send("app#com.example.desktop:connectionName", "methodName",textToSend); 
}
```

From the AIR desktop app:

```
 function onBrowserInvoke (event:BrowserInvokeEvent):void{
    var localConnection:LocalConnection 
    localConnection = new LocalConnection(); 
    localConnection.client = this

    localConnection.allowDomain("example.com");
    localConnection.connect("connectionName");
    }
```

Thank you.
Uli

Comment: Are you sure that you really need specific domain? You can use "portable" local connection name beginning with "_", in your example it'll be "_connectionName" without domain specification before name.

Comment: Just tried it and it doesn't work either. What are other common pitfalls?

Comment: I've checked this code in Flash Builder and it works: Web: localConnection.send("_connectionName", "methodName",textToSend); AIR: localConnection.connect("_connectionName"); Don't forget to make public function methodName in the web swf.

Comment: You can try wild card in allow domain for testing as well: localConnection.allowDomain("*"); in both apps in case you testing not in debug mode.

Comment: It works! Thanks for the "*" wildcard suggestion! One thing I need to find out is how to send only to the Air app with the APP ID _com.example.desktop_ Is this part correct? `localConnection.allowDomain("app#com.example.desktop");`

Comment: Yes it's correct format app#appid:_myConnection for the given app id and it works for me: SWF:   localConnection.allowDomain("app#airtest");  localConnection.connect("_myConnection"); AIR: localConnection.send("_myConnection", "methodName", textToSend); Note that connection name uses _ for unpredictable domain names.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Everything is working now!

Comment: Ok, pleased to help you, I'll copy this to answers as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The working code is:

```
AIR:
    var localConnection:LocalConnection = new LocalConnection();
    localConnection.send("_myConnection", "methodName", "Hello world! Source: http://www.foobar.com"); 
SWF:
    var localConnection:LocalConnection = new LocalConnection();
    localConnection.allowDomain("app#airtest"); //or use "*" wildcard to allow any domains and AIR applications
    localConnection.client = this;
    localConnection.connect("_myConne‌​ction");
```

Where `airtest` is the app id for AIR application. Use the `_` symbol before local connection name for supporting unpredictable domain names (it'll work in debug mode and via http).

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the "_" underscore helps for unpredictable domain names? (Or point to a source that explains what it is used for)

Comment: yes, sure, take a look on live docs [Different domains with unpredictable domain names](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html)