# AS3: How to call an AIR for Desktop from SWF

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I'm trying to code or call the AIR [for desktop] from SWF, so SWF to AIR. Can't find any good codes. Can someone help me how can I code it.?

Assuming my SWF filename is MAIN.swf
then for the AIR is DETAILS.airi

So in my MAIN.swf, I have a button there where when I click it, it will proceed to the DETAILS.airi. Is it possible to call the AIR came from sWF?.

Thank you in advance for the reply.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956316/open-a-native-air-app-via-url

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LocalConnection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappshtml/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7c7e.html) to communicate between SWF and AIR.

[As3 - LocalConnection between SWF and AIR desktop app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14234833/as3-localconnection-between-swf-and-air-desktop-app)